# Getting bitmapdrawable from fresco

Tags: java, android, fresco

I'm trying to get the bitmap that from SimpleDraweeView.

I already setted my SimpleDraweeView with uri image:

```
final Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                    .scheme(UriUtil.LOCAL_RESOURCE_SCHEME)
                    .path(returnUri.getPath())
                    .build();
            profileImage.setImageURI(returnUri);
```

And now I'm trying to save the image in the memory (storage) of the phone.

```
 Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) profileImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); //  ImageDiskHelper.drawableToBitmap(profileImage.getDrawable().get);
        try {
            ImageDiskHelper.saveToInternalStorage(b, "MyActualProfileImage");
        } catch(Exception c){ }
```

But If I use the code above I get :  com.facebook.drawee.generic.RootDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

I convert profileImage.getDrawable to bitmap the image is like this:  [empty image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbDrk.png)

I'm trying to get the bitmap which is being displayed by the SimpleDraweeView

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Fresco already manages all the caching etc. for you.

Comment: @AlexanderOprisnik A good reason I can think of is for UI testing it's useful to have access to a bitmap drawable, but to do that we need to start with a regular drawable it seems, and I don't know how to cast that

Comment: Because I want to the user see some image then save it into storage

Answer (score 1):

Getting the bitmap drawable is not a good idea since the underlying implementation of Fresco could change in the future, which would break your code.

I guess you really just want the raw encoded image bytes (so that you don't have to re-encode the image).
You can get the encoded image bytes with

`DataSource<CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer>>
    dataSource = imagePipeline.fetchEncodedImage(imageRequest, callerContext);`

Since you already fetched the image before, it should be available instantly and you can do something like

```
try {
  CloseableReference<PooledByteBuffer> encodedImage = dataSource.getResult();
  if (imageReference != null) {
    try {
      // Do something with the encoded image, but do not keep the reference to it!
      // The image may get recycled as soon as the reference gets closed below.
    } finally {
      CloseableReference.closeSafely(encodedImage);
    }
  } else {
    // cache miss
    ...
  }
} finally {
  dataSource.close();
}
```

Don't forget to close the references so that you don't leak memory.
You can find more information [here](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-image-pipeline.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be help you.

```
SimpleDraweeView view = findView(R.id.pic);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
if (bitmap != null) {
    dominantColor = getDominantColor(bitmap);
}
```

Maybe it's not beautiful solution, but working well for me.